# how do you change the file date format in windows explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer

for example, the "date modified" column displays its dates with just the day of the week and the time it was modified. how can this be changed, and for the sake of my own curiosity, why is this the default? it's been frustrating and useless every time i've ever needed to use that information as i'm browsing files

Comment: Start > Control Panel > Region and Language > Formats and play with the date formats and/or click Additional Settings > Reset

Comment: tried that, unfortunately. not sure what it's supposed to change, but it didn't seem to have any effect on these dates

Comment: In many file lists, dates within the last week or so are shown as day and time; farther back as date and time.  It's a simple way to make recent files stand out, which is often what users need.

Comment: i wish it worked that way! that would actually be useful xD